# Dynamically add items to a checklist (which is a form)

Tags: angular, forms

I want to create a form for adding items to a checklist, where the minimum of items is 1, but the maximum is unknown. To achieve that, I tried to dynamically add formControls to a form. I´ve several issues with that:

1. when I initally insert a value for first item and press the + button, no new field for second item is rendered
2. when I press the + plus button a second time a new field is rendered incompletly (means material style is not applied)
3. additionally I push the strings into a string[], but this has just empty strings

I prepared a stackblitz-demo for you, thx for any help
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ayejpy?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use formarray to deal with dynamic array elements

```js
// add a formarray to form
checklist: this.formBuilder.array([]),

// add a getter for a formarray
get checklist() {
  return this.formGroup.get('checklist') as FormArray;
}

//write a fn to add/remove elements to formarray
modifyCheckList(index: number, mode: boolean) {
  const formArray = this.checklist;
  const value = index > 0 ? formArray.at(index).value : null;
  if (mode) {
    formArray.push(new UntypedFormControl(value, [Validators.required]));
  } else {
    formArray.removeAt(index);
  }
}

// add first array item checklist
this.modifyCheckList(0, true);
```

modify your template to accept these new elements

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
...
<ng-container formArrayName="checklist">
  <div *ngFor="let checklistPoint of checklist.controls; let i = index; let isFirst=first; let isLast = last;">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Checklist-ToDo {{ i + 1 }}</mat-label>
      <input matInput [formControlName]="i" required />
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" type="button" (click)="modifyCheckList(i, true)" [disabled]="!isLast">
      +
    </button>
    <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" type="button" (click)="modifyCheckList(i, false)" [disabled]="isLast">
      -
    </button>
  </div>
</ng-container>

{{formGroup.value|json}}
...
</form>
```

Updated Stackblitz for your reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dfbxwe

Comment: Thx very much, you helped me a lot

Comment: I used your Code for an addChecklistModal, now I have the problem that I´m not able to also store ids as keys in that array within the editChecklistModal. I have made a stackblitz again: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kdp5nq?file=src%2Fmain.ts , maybe you have also some tips for me.

Comment: you can use a custom form control with hidden item as id and the whole custom control will be an item of form array